On a sentence of J.Nekovar in the introduction of "Selmer complexes"
In his famous book "Selmer complexes", J.Nekovar, speaking about Greenberg conditions, wrote the following sentence (see 0.8.1 p.10)

these are the only local conditions that can be handled by elementary
methods; the general case would require a heavy dose of crystalline machinery, which
is not yet available.

Even though I know all the concepts involved in this sentence, I have absolutely no idea what it means. More precisely

What does he mean by “the only local conditions that can be handled by elementary
methods" ? EDIT as pointed out in the comments "elementary methods" are methods used in the book but the question is rather why Greenberg's conditions are the only ones to which these methods apply.

What was not available in crystalline cohomology at the time he wrote this sentence?



I think the "elementary methods" refer to the content of the book itself. Nekovář uses the local conditions at places above $p$ to be the Greenberg conditions. I don't know what $p$-adic Hodge theory was/is missing to replace them by $H_f$ conditions in general.

See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.7386

@ChrisWuthrich Yes you right this was obvious but the second question is less obvious I think.

@coLaideronnette thank you very much, but could you be a little bit more precise, where do you think I might find an answer in this paper?

No but wait @ChrisWuthrich, I agreed to quickly. Indeed, the elementary methods are those used in the book but my question (which was not clear enough so I will edit it) is why Greenberg's conditions are the only ones to which these methods apply.

Oh I found it @coLaideronnette it allows us to connect the Greenberg Selmer group and that of Bloch-Kato'! It's really enlightening, thank you very much!
